# zsh script not working

Tags: bash, zsh

I have several commands I have to execute to compile my assembly file, so I decided to write a script for it. Commands I need to compile `hello.asm`:

```
nasm -fmacho64 hello.asm ; creates hello.o file which I need to compile with gcc
gcc -o exe hello.o -lSystem
```

So I wrote a script that does that, also executes result and deletes everything:

```
nasm -fmacho64 $1
temp=${$1/.asm/.o}
gcc -o exe $temp -lSystem
./exe
rm exe
rm $temp
```

I'm doing it on `zsh`, but I checked that substitution works the same on `bash` and `zsh`. And it says `bad substitution` and some other errors following it:

```
➜ ./asm_execute.sh hello.asm
./asm_execute.sh: line 2: ${$1/.asm/.o}: bad substitution
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
./asm_execute.sh: line 4: ./exe: No such file or directory
rm: exe: No such file or directory
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

Comment: `${$1/.asm/.o}` should be `${1/.asm/.o}` ... you should consider using `make` for stuff like this imho

Comment: Also, if it's a `zsh` script, I'd give it the `.zsh` extension or no extension at all instead of that misleading `.sh` one (and make sure to add the right she-bang). Beware bash, zsh and POSIX sh languages are different and incompatible (both bash and zsh have a mode in which they can interpret `sh` code, but note that `${param/pattern/replacement}` is not part of the `sh` language, that comes from ksh).

Answer (score 2):

You have 1 too many `$` signs in your expression.

You can either say `$1` or `${1}` to access the value of the first parameter. If you want to modify the value then you need to use the second form. So what you want is `${1/.asm/.o}` - no second `$` inside the braces.

Comment: Note that `${${1}/.asm/.o}` like `${${1}}` would work in `zsh` as expansion operators can be nested there as long as you use the `${...}` form, but the `${}` would still be redundant. It could be useful in things like `${${1/%.asm/.o}/%.C/.c}` for instance.